# Which rotation is shown in the Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The chest bone of my player can be rotated while aiming.

Now I wanted to evaluate how much (minimum and maximum rotation) I should let the chest be rotatable.

To do that, I allowed all degrees of rotation and took a look at the Inspector.

For example, the minimum value that the chest should be rotatable to the left should be Y=-15.
At Y=-15 (seen in the Inspector), it still looked natural.

Now I wanted to code this.

To my surprise, chest.localRotation.Y was a completely different value than what the Inspector is showing.

I have then taken a look at the chest variable and extended the view.
I just can't see the rotation value that the Inspector is showing.

How should I go on in this case, please?

I'm using this to rotate the bone:

```
Chest.LookAt(ChestLookTarget.position); 
Chest.rotation = Chest.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(Offset);
```

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: It's the `localRotation` .. or better said one of the many possible euler angle representations of the `Quaternion` value. So `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.EulerAngles(17.815f, -15.395f, 0.746f);` and `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.EulerAngles(5.0f, 316.9f, 352.4f)` should kind of have the same result

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you suggest how I should handle this? I mean I need to limit the rotation somehow. :-)

Comment: You can try an `if (transform.localRotation.Y < value) { transform.localRotation.Y = value;}`

Comment: @nothing nope, OP already said he tried that and .. reading and setting `Quaternion` values usually is never a good idea! `Quaternion`s have 4 values `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` and they are kind of normalized in a way that their sum is always `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work:

[`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) is not a human readable value.

One `Quaternion` is allways unique but can have multiple (infinite?) different representations in `Euler` space! The other way round one `Euler` represents allways exactly one `Quaternion` value.

If you look at the docs it explicitly says

> Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.

---

Than as said what you see in the inspector is the [`localRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html) in relation to the parent `Transform`.

Better said it is one of the many possible `Euler` inputs that result in the `Quaternion`. What you see in the debug at [`localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) is another possible `Euler` representation. Unity usually in `localEulerAngles` also gives you only values `> 0`.

---

It seems that the chest anyway will only rotate around the `Y` axis, right?

If this is the case you can simply get the Angle between the chest's original forward vector and the target. It is way easier to handle `Vector3` values than `Quaternion`s ;)

It seems to be the same use case as in [this post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1501056/view.html)

```c#
// get the target direction
Vector3 targetDir = ChestLookTarget.position - Chest.position;

// Reset any difference in the Y axis
// since it would change the angle as well if there was a difference I the height
// between the two objects
targetDir.y = 0;

// however you currently rotate
// instead rotate only the Vector3 variable without applying it to the transform yet
Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(Chest.forward, targetDir, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);

// Compare the target direction to the parents forward vector
float newAngle = Vector3.Angle(Chest.parent.transform.forward, newDir);

if (newAngle > MaxRotationAngle)
{
    // What should happen if angle gets bigger?
    return;
}

// If angle still okey set the new direction
Chest.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
```

Comment: The Chest bone should also be able to rotate up and down.